# Where does AWS API Gateway get the JWKS Uri?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway

As I configured authorization in my API Gateway via JWT, AWS needs the JWKS URI to verify my token. I currently use auth0 for that. I know from the documents from auth0 that its

```
[ISSUER_URL]/.well-known/jwks.json
```

But I haven't set it at AWS. In Google's Cloud solutions there is the value `x-google-jwks_uri` but in AWS there wasnt something like this.

Comment: The `.well-known` part is there because the url is ... well-known. AWS can just assume the URL to be there and access the jwks.json in that directory. Does it currently not work or are you just wondering why it actually does work!?

Comment: I am just wondering why its working like this.

Comment: Okay, then that is the answer. The url is well-defined and well-known, there is no need to be able to configure it.